# Azure DevOps self hosted windows build agent fails git remote clone (128)

Tags: azure-devops

Really confused by all this.

A few days ago I set up a windows azure vm.
I installed the build agent from azure devops
Followed the instructions for installation
*and all was working!*

Today - for some reason - it is complaining about not being able to read my git password:

```
Git fetch failed with exit code: 128
```

Nothing has changed.
No new PAT
No expired PAT

I figured I would remove the agent from the machine and reinstall and configure the agent - which I was kind of hoping wouldnt have worked because I then wouldnt be able to trust it in the future.

Sure enough it didnt work

Does anyone know what might be up?

A bonus question too - does anyone know if there is "just a build image I can use"?  Liek the ones Azure uses?  I see the repo on github and it has a load of scripts but not sure how you run them.  Individually?  Is there a master script I just cant see?

Thanks all!

Comment: I will also add that I logged into the windows vm and tried to manually clone a repo.  It asked for my credentials.  I didnt give them.  I swear the instructions say that the only scopes the PAT require are Agent and Deployment.  Which makes me wonder how it even has rights to clone code......

Comment: In command-line in pipeline, we need to add git credentials or PAT in the git clone command, so that the command can have rights to clone code.  And the PAT we enter when installing agent is just used for authentication of agent itself. It doesn't mean the git command running in that agent can automatically access the PAT for authentication.

Comment: thanks for the response: firstly,  the machine was working when i first set everything up. secondly, i thought the context was pssed to the build agent when it gets a job.  it is this token that gives the build agent rights to pull code and do stuff. it shouldnt have to run unde mine or any other user context.  thirdly why is this not in the documentation? ive never had to do it before.  i dont doubt what you say may work but i worry that it isnt stable if i do t understand why it just stopped all of a sudden. maybe some sort of permissions on the build agent configuration in AZDO?

Comment: For `the machine was working when i first set everything up`, do you run the same pipeline with same tasks? Can you tell me when you get your original error? I once thought you got that error when running something like cmd task or ps task, but now it looks like you're using github repo as source and getting that error when starting the pipeline?

Comment: @lance on the money, sir.  i was using pipelines. and all was working well.  then for - seemingly - no reason, it decides it wants credentials.  i did attempt to git clone manually - but that was a side note.  nothing to do with anything.  to be clear, this is an azure devops pipeline building from an azure devops git repo.  the build box is a windows 10 box.  i am going to put it down to expired PAT but cant confirm it.

Comment: Hmm, trying creating a new PAT to test, normally the pat will expire in 30 days.

Comment: Im not sure I mentioned that I rebuilt the box and all is working.  And this time I am monitoring the PAT expiration.  I think we can close this one now.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, if you have any update with this issue when monitoring the expiration, feel free to let me know.

Comment: I am actually working on this right now as it has happened again.  I am getting: "fatal: could not read Password for" on the git clone.  When I use the Azure Pipeline all is well, but when i use the self hosted it doesnt like it and I have idea why.  Same code.  Which makes me think I have not or mis configured something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the answer to **my** problem.  I have read a lot of only helpful posts and they all point to different issues to the same error message.

It turns out that my ~/.gitconfig had the contents of my known_hosts file.

:|

I dont know how it happened, but it did.  I deleted it and the git clone is working!

Thanks Lance and all!

Comment: Stressing this was the right answer for me as well. For future reference, no issue deleting the .gitignore file. I still cannot understand how this file was created (1 year ago) and suddently it fails one year later...

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know what might be up?

When cloning azure devops repos using cmd.exe in local machine, we can use simple command like `git clone URL`. The URL comes from Azure Devops Repos=>Clone:

[image]

If it's one **private** azure devops repos, normally in **local machine** it will display a popup window for authentication. But now since we're running that command in pipeline job, we can't sign in with that popup window.

For this, there're two available choices:

1.git clone `https://UserName:Password@dev.azure.com/OrgName/ProjectName/_git/RepoName`

Replace username and password with those values after clicking the button. Replace those OrgName,ProjectName,RepoName with your actual ones.

[image]

2.Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#use-your-personal-access-token), you can also use PAT in that command like: `git clone https://anything:{yourPAT}@dev.azure.com/OrgName/ProjectName/_git/RepoName`

Replace {yourPAT} with your PAT. Replace those OrgName,ProjectName,RepoName with your actual ones.

Comment: I have this same problem as well. Although your solution works, I'm concerned with the PAT being coupled to a user account. If that user leaves the company, that PAT will stop working, thereby, causing the pipelines to fail.